# improving express.js module usage

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

There is something small but it annoys me. When you want to use a node module you have to manually install it, required it and add it in package.json. If you don't want to use it it's the same thing backwards.

Is there a tool that install/remove to/from node_modules & add/remove to/from package.json automatically after module is required.

It's something simple that must exists if not now later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite an interesting question. I couldn't find a solution so I wrote a small script myself. Imagine you have your main file with the following content.

index.js:

```
var colors = require('colors');
console.log('this comes from my main file');
```

In case you don't have `colors` installed and run `node index.js` you'll get the error `Error: Cannot find module 'colors'`.

To make this work create another `module.js` file that you will run instead of your `index.js` file.

module.js:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

try {
  // require your main file here
  require('./index');
} catch(e) {
  if (e.code === 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') {
    var message = e.message;
    console.log(message);
    var module = message.match(/\'([a-z]+)\'/)[1];
    console.log('Installing ' + module + ' ...');
    exec('npm install ' + module + ' --save', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      if (error) console.log(error);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(stdout).replace(/\\n/g, "") + ' successfully installed');
    });
  }
}
```

Now run `node module.js` and you'll get the following

```
Cannot find module 'colors'
Installing colors ...
"colors@0.6.0-1 node_modules/colors" successfully installed
```

If you run `node module.js` again you'll get

```
this comes from my main file // this is what you want
```

and `colors` is added to your `package.json` file. You can reuse `module.js` in every project and just have to change the `require` function to get the right file.

Comment: you rock :) with little work on how it's used will be a great module to install and forget about using npm install :)

Answer (score 1):

npm can do it with the `--save` flag: `npm install [package] --save` or `npm install [package] --save-dev` for devDependencies. Check out the npm install docs: https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html

Comment: That is great, but it's not the thing i'm searching. I want to type "var passport = reguire('passport')". And after the next run (i use nodemon so it will run after save) something to check i if there is an installed passport module, if not ... installed it and add it in to package.json.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not aware of any thing in node that can do that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any tool that will automatically install a package when you modify source code. Shouldn't be that hard to make if you really want it though :)

As Kyle said, `--save` can work for what you want. There is also `npm shrinkwrap` that will take a snapshot of your `node_modules` and update the file it manages for you. Just check that file into git, and then if you deploy to Heroku (or anywhere else that uses `npm install`), it will use that instead of the `package.json` file for dependencies.